# After targeting a div on another page, how do I style it on the parent page?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page on which I called a div from another page like so:

```
$('.target-div').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio.php #portfolio-sports');
```

`#portfoliosports` is a div container that contains several divs with the class `.runner` that I would like to alternate the background color of. How is this done?

Comment: Assuming this request works, and isn't blocked by CORS as it's a cross-domain request, then you can style it exactly as you normally would with CSS.

Comment: Is your question about loading data into a container, or, about alternating the color of divs with the same class?

Comment: it is located on the same site

Comment: it is located on the same site request. The example I am using is just that, an example. The code that I am using is infact working.

Comment: In which case use CSS as my first comment mentioned. The fact the content is dynamically loaded makes no difference

Comment: That does not work, I have tried it

Comment: css should handle this just fine. If it doesn't, show your work. The fact that this content was pulled in via ajax is irrelevant.

Comment: This seems too broad for a good SO question. Consider adding more details/example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with CSS like in this example here:
(you maybe need to turn off the adblocker plugin in your browser, to load the external content)

```js
$('.target-div').load('https://corsproxy.github.io/ #how');
```

```css
.target-div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

/*Styles for the element loaded via jQuery*/
.grey {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="target-div"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think the bug is somewhere else in your code. Can you provide your whole code or maybe an example with JSFiddle or CodePen?